# After installing Windows 7, my MacMini won't boot Lion anymore

Tags: macos, bootcamp, startup, windows

I installed Windows 7 Ultimate 32bits in a MacMini 2,1 using bootcamp. I used a DVD media with multiply choices trough an external sata superdrive with usb adaptor. Windows seams ok, with the exception that I can't eject the disk from that superdrive... things to solve later.

Problem is now it will only boot Windows. I tried to boot with Alt pressed and nothing. So I edited the BCD file with easyBCD 2.3, add the Lion in the list and check it as default. Now the boot stops in a text screen of Windows Boot Manager, both systems are listed in the middle. If I chose "NST Mac OS X", will appear a screen with a strange green animal at the top, the windows logo and a countdown below. I can press F8 to escape to a list os OS. This new screen got "Darwin/x86 Boot v5.0.132" description and three logos: OS X, Windows NTFS, Windows (the second HDD though)... and the strange animal above. If I chose the Apple logo, it will returns to first text screen.

How can I make it boot Mac OS X Lion again?

EDIT. Photos of the screens:
[image: Screen Windows Boot Manager]
[image: Little green friend and Win countdown]
[image: Darwin three choices]

Comment: Can you post a picture of this 'weird animal' - anywhere, flikr, imgur etc & post the link here. Someone can then inline it to the question for you. I'm thinking you managed to install a hackintosh version with chameleon [which isn't meant to be used on a real Mac] :/

Comment: I did uploaded some photos. I taken with iPhone and got to wait fot photos to update in macbook, sometimes only in the next day... Back to the point: this is a protuguese version, I don't recall where I got it, but it is very effective when installing in old machines.

Comment: As I thought - you have installed a Chameleon boot loader [which I think is unix-based but I'm not absolutely certain]. Wherever you got that install from, it was never meant to be used on a real Mac, only on a "PC" trying to fake being a Mac. You need to get a **real** Apple installer, not one from some random web page. Honestly I don't know how that would even work on a real Mac, I'm sure it is going to have broken your partition layout. Try booting holding Option... what happens?

Comment: Clever Chameleon... Option key brings the Windows Boot Manager. I tried other keys but it is always the same, startup keys are not affecting boot. I am not sure what to do next, boot managers might ruin my Windows installation, to reinstall Lion too, I just wish to make it multi OS.

Answer (score 1):

So a guy in MacRumors ask me why I didn't install the Boot Camp drivers in Windows yet - I don't know, nobody mention this before (or I really miss this part). The package is more than just drivers, will install a control panel similar to OS X and will change the boot either - just what I was looking for. After install it, I could finally boot from Lion just by selecting in the list of the control panel.

Unfortunately, I cannot copy-paste the link for the Apple page about those drivers because the site will auto switch to pt-br... I think you will find it easily by searching support.apple.com with google. You got to look for instructions about installing old versions of Windows in old Macs, there is an article about this. Just a warning: each system/Windows require a specific package and version (4 ou 5). Pick the right one and you will be happy.

If you got the link in english, please share with us.